# How to filter password-field in the logger of Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, logging, filter, sinatra

If I send the parameters of a form such as `'password'`, in Sinatra's logs I can see:

```
{"api_session":"da1123f8c5edd2d3b7c8b43a4e93b7c2","password":"12323"}
```

How can I hide the password using asterisks, like `"******"`?

For example, in Rails I can enable a filter for parameters:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  filter_parameter_logging :password
```

Can I do the same in Sinatra?

Comment: An `after` filter is a bandaid that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve this problem another way.

I don't use a form, I send 'put' ajax request with data.

I missed that Sinatra writes to log only my printouts. I can catch all neccessary params and then filter them:

```
put '/api/*' do |path|
  data = request.body.read.to_s
  filtered_data = data
  filtered_data[:password] = '********'
  puts filtered_data #into log
  #...
```

Thank you Tin!

Answer (score 3):

You don't show how you're defining your form in HTML, but I suspect you're using `method="get"` or not specifying how the browser should send the data to Sinatra and letting it default to `get`.

If I define the form like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="do_form" method="get">
      User: <input name="user"><br>
      Passwd: <input type=password name="passwd"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this as my handler:

```
get '/do_form' do
  puts "got user/password"
end
```

I'll see this in the console when I submit the form using the browser:

```
got user/passwd
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2013 07:43:24] "GET /do_form?user=foo&passwd=bar HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0041
```

Sinatra thinks it's safe to output the parameters received. The same thing happens if I define the form like:

```
<form action="do_form">
```

If, instead, I define it like:

```
<form action="do_form" method="post">
```

and use a `post` handler instead of `get`:

```
post '/do_form' do
  puts "got user/passwd"
end
```

I see this in the logging instead:

```
got user/passwd
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2013 07:49:24] "POST /do_form HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0015
```

This is the code I used to test this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
'
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- <form action="do_form"> -->
    <!-- <form action="do_form" method="get"> -->
    <form action="do_form" method="post">
      User: <input name="user"><br>
      Passwd: <input type=password name="passwd"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
'
end

get '/do_form' do
  puts "got user/passwd"
end

post '/do_form' do
  puts "got user/passwd"
end
```

Simply change the definition of the form in the `get '/'` handler to try using either `post` or `get`.

A `get` request puts all the parameters into the URL when the form is sent. It's understandable that Sinatra would output those parameters in its log at that point, since they were sent "in the clear" per the form's `get` definition.

Changing the form to use `post` puts the parameters into the body of the incoming data, not as part of the URL, more effectively hiding them from prying eyes. Sinatra responds by not showing the parameters in its output.

You, as the web-developer, have to be aware of the effect of using either `get` or `post` as the form's `method`. If you aren't in charge of the form, whoever is should have known the effect of using `get` and that it would put the parameters into the URL. A `password` field, or any fields that are `hidden` or should be invisible, can't be used in a form using `method="get"` because this is the expected and defined behavior of HTML and browsers. Either way, fix the form and the rest of the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Good points, but this doesn't address the actual question. Assume the asker has a requirement you're not aware of.

Comment: Then they are supposed to put that in their question. We can try second guessing them but that's a long, slippery, slope. There are times their question is very likely an XY question and I'll propose an answer that should head off the Y-aspect of it, otherwise it's a case of finding a reasonable balance. It's up to the OP to clarify if answers don't meet their needs.

Comment: No, it's not the asker's obligation to state that there are requirements. It's courteous for answerers to assume that the question being asked is the one to answer. Providing ideas for alternate solutions is terrific, and can be done in addition to asking the original question.